# How to always return the executed value of a getter in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema with a getter function for one of the properties, for example:

```js
const User = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        active: Boolean,
        email:  {type: String, get: toLowerCase}
    }
)
```

and toLowerCase is defined as:

```js
function toLowerCase(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase()
}
```

When I perform User.findOne(), an example object returned looks like

```js
// user
{
    active: true,
    email: "LowerCase@gmail.com" // note: not lower-cased
}
```

BUT if access the email property with same object with user.email it returns lowercase@gmail.com

```js
user.email // lowercase@gmail.com
```

Is there a way to have mongo directly return the executed getter value?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Mongoose executes getters when converting a document to JSON. That means that `email` field in the result from `User.findOne()` will not be in lowercase. But, in the moment when you send your data back with `res.json()`, getter will be executed and the `email` field will be set to lowercase value.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I understand there is a way to override the behavior to not run the getters when converting to JSON, but I take it there's no way to run the getters by default without first converting to JSON?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: Running lean() does not work. In this case the getter did not run at all, and accessing user.email is still not loweredcased at all. I expected this might be the case since running a query with lean() removes the "mongo magic"

Comment: Consider sending them a message and ask them directly.